# Python - pandas remove duplicate rows based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a csv which has data that looks like this

```
id   | code  | date
-------------+-----------------------------
| 1  | 2     | 2022-10-05 07:22:39+00::00   |  
| 1  | 0     | 2022-11-05 02:22:35+00::00  |
| 2  | 3     | 2021-01-05 10:10:15+00::00  |
| 2  | 0     | 2019-01-11 10:05:21+00::00  |
| 2  | 1     | 2022-01-11 10:05:22+00::00  |
| 3  | 2     | 2022-10-10 11:23:43+00::00  |
```

I want to remove duplicate `id` based on the following condition -

- For `code` column, choose the value which is not equal to 0 and then choose one which is having latest timestamp.
- Add another column `prev_code`, which contains list of all the remaining value of the code that's not present in `code` column.

Something like this -

```
id   | code  | prev_code
-------------+----------
| 1  | 2     |  [0]     | 
| 2  | 1     |  [0,2]   |
| 3  | 2     |  []      |
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a sleeker solution but something along the following lines should work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
lastcode = df[df.code!=0].groupby('id').apply(lambda block: block[block['date'] == block['date'].max()]['code'])
prev_codes = df.groupby('id').agg(code=('code', lambda x: [val for val in x if val != lastcode[x.name].values[0]]))['code']
pd.DataFrame({'id': map(lambda x: x[0], lastcode.index.values), 'code': lastcode.values, 'prev_code': prev_codes.values})
```

Comment: Thanks @radof. I have to modify the logic, but I got the gist of it.